# Different combinations of $A<B<C$?

Tags: combinatorics

If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are integers between $1$ and $10$ (inclusive), how many different combinations of $A$, $B$, and $C$ exist such that $A<B<C$?

My Answer: There are $\binom{10}{3} = 120$ of choosing $3$ numbers from $10$. However, once the $3$ numbers are chosen only $1$ arrangement out of $6$ possibilities will result in the required configuration, which implies there are $20$ such combinations. Does this make sense?

Thank You

Comment: $\binom{10}{3}$ doesn't count all $6$ arrangements of $3$ chosen numbers, so you shouldn't be dividing it by $6$ at all. For every choice of $3$ distinct numbers in $\{1,\cdots,10\}$ there is a unique way to designate their values as $A,B,C$ with $A<B<C$.

Comment: $\binom{10}{3} $ is the number of 3-element subsets of (a set of size) 10. The natural ordering of the elements of each subset is the arrangement you're interested in; the other arrangements/permutations aren't counted, so no need to divide by 6.

Comment: @anon I am unable to find the connection between choosing 3 distinct numbers from 10 and finding the number of cases when $A<B<C$.

Comment: @BrianO I dont know how to solve this question then.

Comment: I think you do - you did. Choosing a subset of 10 is not the same thing as choosing 3 numbers between from {0, ... 9} without replacement. In the latter case, you might choose (4, 7, 1) in that order. But when "choosing" a *subset*, you're choosing {1, 4, 7}, period. As you observed, there are 120 ways to do that.

Comment: @Jojo You no longer have to find the connection between choosing 3 distinct numbers and finite the number of triples $(A,B,C)$ for which $A<B<C$, because I explained the connection in my first comment: for every choice of $3$ distinct numbers there is a unique way to designate their values $A,B,C$ with $A<B<C$.

Comment: I found 120 to be correct also.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to divide by $10 \choose 3$ by 6, the answer is simply 120. $10 \choose 3$ gives you the number of distinct 3-number combinations in the range [1, 10], and for each combination you can assign A to the lowest, B to the middle number, and C to the highest number.

You would need to divide by $3! = 6$ if you start with $10 * 9 * 8$ instead of $10 \choose 3$, because each 3-number set shows up 6 times here and they are not all 'ordered correctly', as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Total number of ways to select 3 numbers between 1 to 10 (inclusive) = 10C3 = 720
But we need the numbers to be in ascending order.
A

so possible values for C are : 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

when C = 3, then total possible ways is only 1 : 1,2,3

when C = 4, then A,B can take values among 1,2,3 in ascending order, so total ways = 3C2

when C = 5, total possibilities for A,B = 4C2
.

.

.

.

.

when C = 10, then A,B possibilities = 9C2

So total possible ways = 1 + 3C2 + 4C2 + 5C2 + ....+ 9C2 = **120**

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).